# XSD unique with keyref with multiple parameters

Tags: xml, xsd

Considering the following XML

```
<Register name="Error">
  <Bits name="count">
     <lsb>0</lsb>
     <msb>3</msb>
  </Bits>
</Register>

<Register name="Date">
  <Bits name="minutes">
     <lsb>0</lsb>
     <msb>1</msb>
  </Bits>
  <Bits name="seconds">
     <lsb>2</lsb>
     <msb>3</msb>
  </Bits>
</Register>

<parameter name="errors_count">
   <register>
      <!-- /Register@Error/Bits@count exists OK -->
      <name>Error</name>
      <bits>count</name>
   <register>
<parameter> 

<parameter name="seconds">
   <register>
      <!-- /Register@Date/Bits@count doesn't exist INVALID -->
      <name>Date</name>
      <bits>count</name>
   <register>
<parameter>
```

How can I make sure that the given register name and bits exist in withing the same "Register" tag in XSD with the Register@name - Bits@name pair?

Comment: I've read your description three times and I don't understand the question. Showing us some examples of valid and invalid elements might help.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it is impossible with XSD. The only way to fix this would be changing the XML structure:
[XSD key/keyref: hierarchical key structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/891324/xsd-key-keyref-hierarchical-key-structure)